# Basic form validation: why won't my class be added or removed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a button disabled by default and have it become only active once a user has filled out fields marked with a class.

Here's the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/co3d5phy/2/

My jQuery looks like this:

```
function checkForAnswers() {
  var count = $('.pdf-checklist-17012[value!=""]').length;
  var total = $('.pdf-checklist-17012').length;

  if (count == total) {
    $('.pdf-17012').removeClass('disabled');
    $('.pdf-17012').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('.pdf-17012').addClass('disabled');
    $('.pdf-17012').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  console.log(count + '/' + total);
}

checkForAnswers();
$('.pdf-checklist-17012').on('keyup', checkForAnswers);
```

The jsFiddle appears not to work, and the console in Chrome when I view it live logs `0/5` regardless of how many fields are completed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the value html attribute which will not change.
You can fix that with somethink like that:

```
var count = $('.pdf-checklist-17012').filter(function(){
    return $(this).val() !== "";
}).length;
```